# Round to upper integer in Fast-Report VCL

Tags: fastreport

I want to round decimal value to upper integer, for example

```
10.25 = 11
30.79 = 31
1.1 = 2
```

The round function in Fast-Report will round to nearest not the upper integer.

I'm using **PascalScript** language for Fast-Report coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ceiling returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to d.

Example:

> Ceiling(1.7) = 2

If not available you could try this workaround:

> x = 1.1

> Round(x+0.49) = 2

Comment: I couldn't find Ceiling function, I'm using Fast-Report VCL

Comment: @NST you could try to create your own ceil function.